# Swift – "No such module 'Stripe3DS2'" after updating Stripe to 21.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, stripe-payments

I've updated the Stripe SDK to the latest version **21.0.1** via CocoaPods.

When I'm building the project I'm always getting the following error:

`No such module 'Stripe3DS2'` in the `STP3DS2AuthenticateResponse.swift` file.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I just fixed it by updating CocoaPods itself from 1.9 to 1.10

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using SwiftUI. I was wondering if you are using SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: @SwiftUser I'm using UIKit.

Comment: Ah, I had same issue with SwiftUI. I managed to fix it by using Swift Package Manager. Just added this incase anyone else ever has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to updating CocoaPods, I also had to start using Swift Packages in Xcode to import Stripe into my project. Steps are:

Remove this line from Podfile:

```
pod 'Stripe'
```

Re-install pods:

```
pod install
```

Then, add Stripe as a Swift Package by selecting the Project in Xcode, then selecting the 'Swift Packages' tab, then the plus button, and entering the link to the Stripe iOS repo:

```
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios
```

After all this, I could build and run. I'm using SwiftUI in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I added Stripe as a Swift Package. I would only add 'import Stripe' and it would give this error. Turns out that file was included in my app and the App Clip didn't have the libraries linked into it. Once I added them it worked fine.

So the problem may be target inclusion and library linking.